# Sitecore Commerce Documetation 10.1 is not working

Tags: sitecore-commerce, documentation

I have opened the Sitecore.Experience.Commerce.SDK.Documentation.chm that comes with the XC 10.1 installation.

It shows no content for any of the nodes. Could this be a bug.

[image]

Comment: Try to double click on CreateCustomerAddressBlock class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unblock your file.

- Locate the blocked file (your chf/chm file)
- Right-click on the file and select Properties from the menu.
- Click Unblock on the General tab.
- Click OK.

[image]

Source: https://thirtysix.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202921675-How-to-Unblock-a-File-Downloaded-from-an-Email-or-the-Internet